# How do I remove a file from a git repository with dulwich?

Tags: python, dulwich

With dulwich I can stage a file using `repo.stage`, but how do I remove a file ?

I am looking for the equivalent of `git rm`

Answer (score 0):

You can "stage" a file that no longer exists, which will remove it. Alternatively, there is also a `dulwich.porcelain.remove` function that provides the equivalent of `git rm` (i.e. removes the file if it exists and then unversions it).